# Python SciPy IndexError: the length of bounds is not compatible with that of x0

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy, scipy

I'm new to optimizations using Python and scipy. I'm getting the error

```
IndexError: SLSQP Error: the length of bounds is not compatible with that of x0.
```

when trying to pass the `bounds` parameter into `scipy.optimize.minimize`

```
x0 = np.array([[2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2],[2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2]])
bounds = ( [(0,12000),(0,12000),(0,12000),(0,12000),(0,12000),(0,12000),(0,12000),(0,12000),(0,12000),(0,12000),(0,12000)], [(0,12000),(0,12000),(0,12000),(0,12000),(0,12000),(0,12000),(0,12000),(0,12000),(0,12000),(0,12000),(0,12000)] )

x_max = optimize.minimize(f, x0.flatten(), method='SLSQP', bounds=bounds)
```

How should `bounds` be defined for such a `x0`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Notice in the example given in the docs for optimize.minimize:

```
>>> bnds = ((0, None), (0, None))
>>> res = minimize(fun, (2, 0), method='SLSQP', bounds=bnds,
...                constraints=cons)
```

that `bnds` is a sequence of tuples. `len(bnds)` equals the length of the initial guess, `x0`, which in the example is `(2, 0)`.

---

In your code `bounds` is a tuple of lists of tuples. It needs to be flattened to a sequence of tuples, such as

```
bnds = bounds[0]+bounds[1]
```

or, more simply,

```
bnds = [(0, 12000)]*22
x_max = optimize.minimize(f, x0.flatten(), method='SLSQP', bounds=bnds)
```

Notice also that bnds is a list of 22 two-tuples, which is consistent with there
being 22 items in `x0.flatten()`:

```
In [19]: x0.flatten()
Out[19]: array([2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2])

In [20]: len(x0.flatten())
Out[20]: 22
```

Answer (score 5):

I was getting the same error but because of a different reason. I tried a toy example where I was optimizing for only one input variable. My bounds variable looked like the following:

```
bnds=((0.0, 100.0))
```

I had to change this to the following to make it work:

```
bnds=((0.0, 100.0),)
```