# Cannot get dimensions of bounds to match in scipy.optimize.fmin_tnc

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

Note: This is not a duplicate of [Python SciPy IndexError: the length of bounds is not compatible with that of x0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29150064/python-scipy-indexerror-the-length-of-bounds-is-not-compatible-with-that-of-x0) . I believe I'm already following the answer there and beside, it's a different function in that library.

I am calling

```
fmin_tnc(self._negative_likelihood,
         [(axis_mean + current_prob) / 2],
         fprime=self._likelihood_gradient,
         args=(axis_mean, axis_std, current_prob, self.total),
         bounds=[tuple(sorted([axis_mean, current_prob]))])
```

The two functions are both static functions, with signatures:

```
(x, axis_mean, axis_std, current_prob, trials)
```

The second unnamed arguments, per the documentation at http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.fmin_tnc.html#scipy.optimize.fmin_tnc , is:

```
x0 : array_like
```

I'm only running fmin_tnc on one set of values at a time, so I make x0 a list of len 1.

The documentation for bounds says:

```
bounds : list, optional
    (min, max) pairs for each element in x0, defining the bounds on that parameter.
```

So I'm passing a list of one sorted tuple, to match the one element of xo. I've tried several other permutations, but I always get:

```
ValueError: length of x0 != length of bounds
```

len(bounds) and len(x0) both return 1. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Any chance you can create a [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://sscce.org/), for readers convenience? Just with very simple functions.

Comment: Check the type and length of `axis_mean` and `current_prob`.  If either is a numpy array, check their `.shape` attribute.

Comment: Thanks. The .shape may have been off. It's working now and I don't think I changed anything. Chalk this up to being a dumb question.